# Autodesk Forge : How to store 3D Models on BOX

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am new to Autodesk services. We are having 1200+ 3D-models of size average 40MB. These models are built in .fbx format using Autodesk products. I have few doubts regarding how to proceed further. Please let me know. Thank you in advance.

1. Can we put our models on BOX. So that we can convert them into svf using Model Derivative API and save the output back in BOX Account. And viewer will be fetching the model file from BOX itself?
2. If yes can you give some references for how to proceed further?
3. If no, what is the costing of Autodesk server? I am aware that the free trial provides 5 GB free. But for further storage what is the cost?
4. My client is in US and customers are from US only, but later on we may move it to worldwide. So if needed can we change the region later on?
5. For now as I am from India, can I select the region to India, because the cost is like 0.6?
6. As we are giving access to models only to authenticated users, is Autodesk fully secure? What storage method/place will be safe?
7. From my forge account how can I see storage usage?
8. For performance wise which is the best solution for storing 3D Models.

Answer (score 1):

1. In order to use Model Derivative APIs, your models must be uploaded to Forge using the Data Management APIs. After that, you could download the generated viewable files to your own storage, however this is not an officially supported workflow.
2. If you still want to serve Forge models from your own storage, this [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-c-net) shows how to obtain a list of all files that must be downloaded for a specific model.
3. With a non-trial Forge subscription, which costs $100 a year, there's no storage limit.
4. The data in Forge can be accessed from anywhere. In case you need to control the actual data center where your data shoud live, when [creating a bucket](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-POST) for your data, you can choose between *US* and *EMEA* regions.
5. At this point the two available geos are *US* and *EMEA*.
6. Forge is secured; you can control access to content stored with Data Management APIs using [2-legged](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-2-legged-token) or [3-legged](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token) OAuth.
7. While in the trial, this information is not available. And as I mentioned above, with an active Forge subscription there's no storage limit.
8. I would recommend storing your CAD data in Forge. It's performant, safe, and again, the Model Derivative APIs can translate models from the Forge storage directly.